# onclick event of dynamically added button

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I need to add `onclick` event to some dynamically added `button`, but when i click the button, the `onclick` event is not fired. I saw some solutions to this, like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495976/handling-an-event-on-a-dynamically-added-button-after-postback) which says I should create the controls and attach the event on `page_init` or `page_load` every time there is a request, but, will this make the website very slow if I have a lot of controls to add?

Comment: Do you really mean asp-classic? This sounds like ASP.NET WEbForms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you **must** recreate dynamic controls if you want to access them and have their events fire on postback.

If you have so many controls on a page that your site is slow, you have a *design* issue. Rethink your design so you do not have so many controls on one page (perhaps several pages/tabs?).

Comment: I think, Memory/HTML rendering cost of the controls should be same while loading/executing. right?

Comment: @PankajGarg - If you don't recreate them, they cost nothing on postbacks ;)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. but memory consumption will. be same in executing and rendering the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> Allocate memory like below to button in `Init Page Event`

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);

void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

---

As told by @Oded, this approach can create Design issue.

When you have a Div like control IN YOUR PAGE which is supposed to consume this Button, then you can GIVE CSS styles to give it proper alignment and proper placement.

---

You have two option.

1. Add control at Runtime
2. Add control at Design Time

Definitely, site will go slow in case of many controls in both cases. As both options will take memory **BUT**, By End of the `Page Life Cycle`, all the controls will get `disposed`.